# getting bulkification issues on SOQL query () : Error List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject 20

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

```
        Map<Id,alu_Internship_Cycle__c> mapIdbyNewInternCyc = new  Map<Id,alu_Internship_Cycle__c>(internCycle);
        System.debug('mapIdbyNewInternCyc'+mapIdbyNewInternCyc);

        Map<Id,alu_Internship_Cycle__c> mapIdbyOldInternCyc = new Map<Id,alu_Internship_Cycle__c> ([
            SELECT Id, Name, Start_Date__c 
            FROM alu_Internship_Cycle__c 
            WHERE Id NOT IN: mapIdbyNewInternCyc.keySet() 
            AND Start_Date__c =: mapIdbyNewInternCyc.values().Start_Date__c.addYears(-1)]);
```

Comment: You're getting an error because a query is assigning multiple values to an SObject variable, you need to make it a list. In the code you show it doesn't look like any of this can cause this error. Are you sure you have the code there?

Comment: yes, I'm getting this error in the below line of code

AND Start_Date__c =: mapIdbyNewInternCyc.values().Start_Date__c.addYears(-1)]);

Comment: @Folkert If you want then I'll share complete code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final line in the OP code:

```
AND Start_Date__c =: mapIdbyNewInternCyc.values().Start_Date__c.addYears(-1)]);
```

"shouldn't" compile.  That said, it wouldn't particularly surprise me if it does compile, and then confuses the SOQL engine into throwing the error you are seeing.  I'm not sure what exactly the line is supposed to do, but assuming you want to get records whose start date is one year before one of the dates in your map, you can use:

```
Map<Id,alu_Internship_Cycle__c> mapIdbyNewInternCyc = new Map<Id,alu_Internship_Cycle__c>(internCycle);
Set<Date> yearBeforeStarts = new Set<Date>();
for(alu_Internship_Cycle__c cycle : mapIDByNewInternCyc.values())
{
    yearBeforeStarts.add(cycle.Start_Date__c.addYears(-1));
}

Map<Id,alu_Internship_Cycle__c> mapIdbyOldInternCyc = new Map<Id,alu_Internship_Cycle__c> ([
        SELECT Id, Name, Start_Date__c 
        FROM alu_Internship_Cycle__c 
        WHERE Id NOT IN: mapIdbyNewInternCyc.keySet() 
        AND Start_Date__c =: yearBeforeStarts]);
```